# Leag Lag and Window Function with concat function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to tranform data from basically merge line until |#| is found in data

[image]

Output Needed

[image]

I have transformed using lead lag function but unsure how to proceed

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.read.text('text.dat')
#Adding index column each row get its row numbers , Spark distributes the data and to maintain the order of data we need to perfrom this action
df_1 = df.rdd.map(lambda r: r).zipWithIndex().toDF(['value', 'index'])
df_1.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber")
#zipindex creates array making back to string
df_2 = spark.sql("select value.value as value , index  from linenumber")
df_2.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber2")
#Splitting and extracting the location value from header and assigning null
df_new = spark.sql("select value,case when value like '%|##|' then value else null end as orgval,case when value like '%|#|' then 1 else 0 end as valrow,index from linenumber2")
w = Window().partitionBy().orderBy(col("index"))
df_new=df_new.select("*", lag("valrow").over(w).alias("validrows"))
df_new.createOrReplaceTempView("linenumber3")
spark.sql("select * from linenumber3 order by index").show(100)
```

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code and explanation:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f, Row
from pyspark.sql.window import Window


df = spark.createDataFrame([
  Row(Value='A', LineNumber=6),
  Row(Value='B', LineNumber=7),
  Row(Value='C', LineNumber=8),
  Row(Value='D|#|', LineNumber=9),
  Row(Value='A|#|', LineNumber=10),
  Row(Value='E', LineNumber=11),
  Row(Value='F', LineNumber=12),
  Row(Value='G|#|', LineNumber=13),
  Row(Value='I', LineNumber=23),
  Row(Value='J', LineNumber=24),
  Row(Value='K', LineNumber=25),
  Row(Value='L', LineNumber=25)
])

df = df.withColumn('filename', f.input_file_name())
df = df.repartition('filename')

w = Window.partitionBy('filename').orderBy('index')

# Creating an id to enable window functions
df = df.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

# Identifying if the previous row has |#| delimiter
df = df.withColumn('delimiter', f.lag('Value', default=False).over(w).contains('|#|'))

# Creating a column to group all values that must be concatenated
df = df.withColumn('group', f.sum(f.col('delimiter').cast('int')).over(w))

# Grouping them, removing |#|, collecting all values and concatenate them
df = (df
      .groupBy('group')
      .agg(f.concat_ws(',', f.collect_list(f.regexp_replace('Value', '\|#\|', ''))).alias('ConcalValue'),
           f.min('LineNumber').alias('LineNumber')))

# Selecting only desired columns
(df
 .select(f.col('ConcalValue').alias('Concal Value'), f.col('LineNumber').alias('Initial Line Number'))
 .sort('LineNumber')
 .show(truncate=False))
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|Concal Value|Initial Line Number|
+------------+-------------------+
|     A,B,C,D|                  6|
|           A|                 10|
|       E,F,G|                 11|
|     I,J,K,L|                 23|
+------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This works for a small file. But it fails for a ral huge files java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: input is too large to fit in a byte array. w = Window.orderBy('index') . Is there any way we can split the files into multiple chunks retaining the order and user input_filename function so that each group stays in same order and then apply agg on them? Will this work. Stuck with the volumne!

Comment: Accepting the answers, but it will not work for bigger volumes

Comment: @Rafa Considering your other questions, I made an update to partition your data by filename, trying to avoid OutOfMemoryError

Comment: I will check prior solution was failing for even one file.. now partition by filename might also have the same volume. I need logic to split the large file to ( file-1-1 file-1-2 file 1-3)  into multiple parts based on the volume in way that last line is not ending in |##|  in order and process the above logic. But the challenge is split of files and mainting the order .. split into equal 3 or 4 parts makign sure that the last line ends with |##| in order so that we can merge back after processing

Comment: @Rafa The previous solution I was ordering the entire dataframe without any partitions, in this case all the data was moving to a single node. I don't know how valid it is to add complex logic to partition your data, it may reach the same performance results at the end.